# Return 3 fields on pop-up - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method, which creates a `stock.picking` from another model:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] 
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'name': 'name',
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_uom': rec.isbn.uom_id.id,
                'date_expected': time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
                'product_uom_qty': rec.qty,
                'location_id': record.location_id.id,
                'location_dest_id': record.location_dest_id.id,
                }
            ))
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'outgoing')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            copy_record.create({
                'origin': record.name,
                'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                'move_lines': order_lines, 
                'move_type': 'direct',
                'priority': '1',
                'company_id': record.company_id.id,
            })
       self.write({'state': 'delivered',},)
```

But 3 fields out of it `company_id`,`location_id` and `location_dest_id` should be loaded on a pop-up before creating the new `stock.picking`.

I've tried this:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['stock.picking'] 
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'name': 'name',
                'product_id': rec.isbn.id,
                'product_uom': rec.isbn.uom_id.id,
                'date_expected': time.strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
                'product_uom_qty': rec.qty,
                'location_id': record.location_id.id,
                'location_dest_id': record.location_dest_id.id,
                }
            ))
        sp_types = self.env['stock.picking.type'].search([
        ('code', '=', 'outgoing')
        ])
        if len(sp_types) > 0:
            copy_record.create({
                'origin': record.name,
                'picking_type_id': sp_types[0].id,
                'move_lines': order_lines, 
                'move_type': 'direct',
                'priority': '1',
                'company_id': record.company_id.id,
            })
    tree_view_id = self.env.ref('stock.vpicktree').id
    form_view_id = self.env.ref('stock.view_picking_form').id
    return {
        'name': ('Stock Picking'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'stock.picking',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'views': [(tree_view_id, 'tree'),(form_view_id, 'form')],
        'view_id':tree_view_id,
        'res_id': [copy_record.id],
        'domain': [('id', 'in', [copy_record.id])]
        }
    self.write({'state': 'delivered',},)
```

But the `return` returns the `stock.picking` view only, and doesn't create anything, how can I modify this to load those 3 fields on pop-up?

I try to keep it simple without wizards, I know that with a wizard this can be achievable, but I just want to modify this method.

Any ideas?

Comment: self.write({'state': 'delivered',},) this code has no effect, it will return then how could execute the code?

Comment: I think I'm going to create a wizard for this, in the end :)